# MacBook Air: Can't connect to my TP-Link wifi router

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I have a MBA 13" mid 12, OS X 10.7.5. It often completely ignores my Wi-Fi network, not showing it in the list of available networks (my Linux boxes and Android devices are connecting perfectly).

I tried to remove my network from the list of known networks, rebooted my router and notebook many times, tried to change encryption standards (now it uses 802.11b/g, WPA/WPA2, TKIP), but network still was not visible.

My router is TP-Link TL-WR340GD.

Answer (score 2):

After long experimenting I've changed my Wi-Fi channel settings on the router from "Automatic" to an average value (8, in the range 1 - 13).

Now the network is well visible.

Ed. Here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/74575/36329 is shown how to check what channels are supported by Apple (Broadcom actually) hardware.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the router mode to 11g mode only .