# How does the language & text region setting "affect the availability of Internet services"?

Tags: system-settings

According to a note underneath the Region setting in the Language & Text prefpane, "Changing the region may affect the availability of Internet services."

This is not explained in any documentation I can find anywhere, and apart from some cryptic suggestions in some mailing lists, I've found essentially nothing to explain how changing the region setting—which seems to only be for changing date, time and number formatting, and is almost always Custom for me—would affect network connectivity.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this note is there, and what it refers to?

Comment: I couldn’t confirm, but it seems like this answer may fit: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108429/37610.